# iText and JavaScript - show confirm() and disable textfields

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, itext

I have a short question regarding iText (2.1.7 for java) and Javascript. I have a form with several textfields and added a button. When I click the button I want to show a hint with "ok" and "cancel" and if its confirmed, I want the textfields to be disabled. Sounds easy, but somehow I have several problems.
1. iText does not execute the app.confirm("Text") from my JavScript. I tried with app.alert("Test") and it works - so I know that my Javascript is found and used at all. But alert is not what I want here.
2. Setting the fields to disabled or readOnly does not work at all.

Right now these are my code-parts:

```
String myJavaScript =

            "function lock(){" +
                    "var confirmed = app.confirm('Test');" +
                    "if(confirmed){" +
                    "this.getField('abnehmer').disabled = true;}}";

    writer.addJavaScript(myJavaScript);
```

Instead of getField I also tried document.getElementById and this.getElementById and it also didn't work.
As the fieldname I use the name of my PdfFormField. I create them like this:

```
private void insertTextFieldAndBox (PdfWriter writer, PdfContentByte contentByte, String fieldNumber, Rectangle box,
                                    String fieldName, String defaultText, boolean multiLined) throws IOException, DocumentException {

    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(contentByte);
    ct.setSimpleColumn(box.getLeft(),box.getBottom(), box.getRight(), box.getTop());
    ct.addElement(createFieldnumber(fieldNumber));
    ct.go();

    TextField kidField = new TextField(writer, box ,null);
    kidField.setText("This is a text");
    kidField.setFont(inside_textbox.getBaseFont());
    kidField.setFontSize(inside_textbox.getSize());
    kidField.setExtraMargin(5,0);
    if(multiLined){
        kidField.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
        kidField.setOptions(TextField.MULTILINE);
    }
    PdfFormField textfield = kidField.getTextField();
    textfield.setFieldName(fieldName);
    writer.addAnnotation(textfield);

}
```

And then for the Button (its inside a table) I use this PdfCellEvent:

```
 class ButtonCell implements PdfPCellEvent {
        protected String fieldname;
        protected String caption;

        public ButtonCell(String fieldname, String caption) {
            this.fieldname = fieldname;
            this.caption = caption;
        }


        public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rectangle, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {

            PdfWriter writer = canvases[PdfPTable.BASECANVAS].getPdfWriter();
            PushbuttonField button = new PushbuttonField(writer, rectangle, "MyButton");
            button.setRotation(90);
            button.setBackgroundColor(new GrayColor(0.75f));
            button.setBorderColor(GrayColor.GRAYBLACK);
            button.setBorderWidth(1);
            button.setBorderStyle(PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_BEVELED);
            button.setTextColor(GrayColor.GRAYBLACK);
            button.setFontSize(12);
            button.setText("Lock document");

            PdfFormField field;
            try {
                field = button.getField();
                field.setAction(PdfAction.javaScript("lock()", writer));
                writer.addAnnotation(field);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: *"iText does not execute the app.confirm("Text") from my JavScript"* - iText does not execute JavaScript at all, a PDF viewer does (or does not). That been said, I don't find a `app.confirm` method specified in the *JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference.* Unless it is a new addition, it is no surprise that it isn't executed.

Comment: I didnt know there existis such a document (JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference) :) Thanks.